# Open Google Play with preferred language from Android Programmatically

Tags: java, android, google-play, locale

I have a application which allow user to set language using the setting. Is it possible to open Google Play from the application based on the language setting of my application instead of the phone?

For example, if I have both `English` and `Japanese` language in the application. And I have my phone setting as `English` and Application setting as `Japanese`. When I click "check out the application in Google play" (using "market://details?id=") from the application. It takes me to the Google play with English setting. Is there any way where I can ask google open with text that is in Japanese?

Something like this?

```
market://details?id=<package_name>&lang="jp"
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the Google Play store's public web API doesn't support language as a parameter. http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html